# why my table is empty when i have no error in php code?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, sql-insert

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
```

Guys I make a table for shoping bag and it name is basket. I get id at product table name and price too. and my basket table is like

`this(id[int],name[varchar],email[varchar],price[decimal],count[int],reduction[int],done[boolean]).`

at the end when I click on a shopping bag that link could add count, but my table is empty no have a row.

```
<body>

    <?php
        include"database.php";
        $name="";
        $price=0;
        $email=$_SESSION["email"];
        $done=false;
        $count=0;
        // i get id form product table and product table like this(id[int],description[text],price[decimal])//

        $id=$_GET["id"];
        $query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=:id";
        $result=$connect->prepare($query);
        $result->bindparam(":id",$id);
        $result->execute();
        while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $name=$row["names"];
            $price=$row["price"];

        }

        // and write a query  for make count and insert or update in basket table;
        $sql="SELECT * FROM basket WHERE name=:name and email=:email and done=:done";
        $result=$connect->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindparam(":name",$name);
        $result->bindparam(":email",$email);
        $result->bindparam(":done",$done);
        $result->execute();
        while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            if(!empty($row["count"])){
                $count=$row["count"];
            }else{
                $count=0;
            }

        }

        if($count>0){
            $upquery="UPDATE basket SET count=:count WHERE name=:name";
            $result=$connect->prepare($upquery);
            $count++;
            $result->bindparam(":count",$count);
            $result->bindparam(":name",$name);
            $result->execute();
        }else{
            // for now i insert the info to table and give 0 value for reduction// 
            $count1=1;
            $reduction=0;
            $inquery="INSERT INTO basket (name,email,price,count,reduction)VALUES(:name,:email,:price,:count,:reduction)";
            $result=$connect->prepare($inquery);
            $result->bindparam(":name",$name);
            $result->bindparam(":email",$email);
            $result->bindparam(":price",$price);
            $result->bindparam(":count",$count1);
            $result->bindparam(":reduction",$reduction);
            $result->execute();
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no PHP error, so why my table is empty?

I echo $email and $name and $price and $done and $done and $reduction and that are correct.

What is wrong please tell me i am beginnثr in programmer world.

Comment: Why the `select` and `update`/`insert`? Can't you just do `insert into ... on duplicate update`?

Comment: Your update clause, makes not that much sense. What you do is update all all customers count for that product name and  are you sure you have only 1 item with that name?

Comment: hi what item did you mean? why update is nonesense? i write update when my $count>0 ...@nbk

Comment: what item name? @nbk

Comment: UPDATE ... WHERE name=:name"  you fill with $name=$row["names"];  from the product table it shut be at least email too

Comment: and please use $status = $result->execute(); if (($status) && ($result->rowCount() > 0))
{print_r($st->errorInfo());} too see if mysql thriws any errors. Error handling should every time be used.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to refine your code I found out a few things:

1. You are a complete PHP beginner and you need a lot of practice to write standard codes. Don't worry, keep coding. It will come by time. So here goes some golden learning points for you.
2. You used while loops which was totally unnecessary here at every place. While loop is or any other loop is used only when you need to fetch all the records (or limited by coding). That's why its termed a loop. It will keep fetching the data unless it doesn't finds anymore. You should just use a simple fetch when the goal is to just use the database values individually as per the record you have selected (say record as per `where id = :id`).
3. You created unnecessary variables which was not needed. You could have directly used those values while writing queries. Parameterized queries are only needed when you are submitting data via a form as there are chances of SQL injection. For hard coding, you can enter direct values. Also, during fetch you created a variable say `$name` to store the value of `$row['names']`. Its okay but many developers do not consider it as a good practice as every variable uses a bit of memory (search google for more info). Use just `$row['names']` everywhere instead.
4. `session_start()` was missing at the top of the page. Without it your `$email` variable won't recognize the session value (email). If you already have it in database.php then fine, but I would recommend it to use individually on every page (considered a good practise) rather than including via an external file.
5. Please use user id to store in session instead of email as user can change an email which will in future disrupt whole database and its not scalable. On the other hand, the auto incremented user id field is something we never touch and is considered unique. Hence, use user id.
6. Please do not use just `$email = $_SESSION['email']` as it will return an undefined error when user is logged out or the session is destroyed and the user visits that page. Use what I gave below instead. It checks if the `$_SESSION['email']` is empty or not and if it is the value will be set to null preventing from undefined error as `$email` is now defined as null. If session exists, it will use the email from the session. Again, please use user id next time instead.
7. As @nbk said your code confused me and really made no sense at all. Why do you want to fetch the count from same table and then update the same table and all. This makes no sense.

I still corrected the errors in your way of coding (this might not solve your problem as I didn't understand your sense of coding at all about counting and updating in same table but copy and paste it/save it somewhere) which should help you learn kind of standard way to code. Please, go through it, understand it and make the necessary changes as required. Hope all this much of writing and effort helps.

Here is your completely improved code with standard way of coding from start to end:

```
session_start();
include("database.php");
$email = (!empty($_SESSION['email']))?$_SESSION["email"]:null; // Please set user id here instead of email next time as you need to pass id in many places.
$done = false;

$product = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = :id");
$product-> bindValue('id', $_GET['id']);
$product-> execute();
$p = $product->fetch(); // While loop is only needed when you want to fetch and display all the records (like in table format) otherwise NOT.

$basket = $connect->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM basket WHERE name = :name and email = :email and done = :done");
$basket-> bindValue(':name', $p['names']);
$basket-> bindValue(':email', $p['email']);
$basket-> bindValue(':done', $done);
$basket-> execute();
$b = $basket->fetch();

if($b['cnt'] > 0){
  $stmt = $connect->prepare("UPDATE basket SET count = :count WHERE name = :name");
  $stmt-> bindValue(':count', $b['cnt']);
  $stmt-> bindValue(':name', $p['names']);
}else{
  $count = $b['cnt']+1;
  $stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO basket(name, email, price, count, reduction)VALUES(:name, :email, :price, :count, :reduction)");
  $stmt-> bindValue(':name', $p['names']);
  $stmt-> bindValue(':email', $email);
  $stmt-> bindValue(':price', $p['price']);
  $stmt-> bindValue(':cost', $count);
  $stmt-> bindValue(':reduction', 0);
}
$stmt-> execute();
```